# how to get telemetry in dji msdk v5 android kotlin

Tags: dji-sdk

I am unable to get the real-time location of aircraft, I didn't find any helpful documents

I want to get real-time location using remote-Id or Flight Control System, https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android-V5/tree/dev-sdk-main . I have tried this documentation but I didn't find anything here